# Can you share wisdom on using HISTIGNORE in bash?

Tags: bash, terminal

I was reading the manpages for bash on the plane and I stumbled across the HISTIGNORE variable.  To test it out, I immediately edited my .profile to define this variable:

```
export HISTIGNORE=ls
```

I tested it out and this is great!  It excludes plain 'ls' commands from my history without excluding more interesting commands with lengthy paths, but having recently harvested a great deal of wisdom from SU I am eager to know what other commands superusers might recommend or other lessons learned.

What can you share about using the HISTIGNORE variable in bash?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

I ignore `ls` without commands, `bg`, `fg`, `exit`, `pwd`, `clear`, `mount` and `umount`:

If you include this in your `HISTIGNORE` string you can suppress anything as you wish by adding a space at the front of the command:

```
"[ \t]*"
```

This is my `HISTIGNORE`:

```
HISTIGNORE="&:ls:[bf]g:exit:pwd:clear:mount:umount:[ \t]*"
```

I've excluded some other stuff that I have in there that are repetitive commands that are unique to my server. Anything you do that is simple is a good thing to exclude.

I have other stuff which I have forgotten to add but I'm miles away from my Linux box so I am going off of memory.

Comment: If the value of `HISTCONTROL` includes "ignorespace" or "ignoreboth", commands that begin with a space are omitted from history. If the value includes "ignore dups" or "ignoreboth", it's the same as "&" in `HISTIGNORE`.

Comment: To me it has also proven useful to histignore the `history` command itself.

Comment: using `"[ \t]*"` ignores command starting with a space or `t`. You want `HISTIGNORE=$'&:ls:[bf]g:exit:pwd:clear:mount:umount:[ \t]*'`

Comment: Well, ignoring commands that started with a `space` or `\t` was the intention. What is that `$` at the front doing there, that looks very weird, I wouldn't do it like that.

Comment: mine is `export HISTIGNORE="history:forget*"` with an alias of `alias forget=""`  . it makes not adding something to your history a little more explicit than a single space.

Comment: @daparic `\t` is not `t` (ie the letter t) which is what the example as written is ignoring and is likely not the intent. The `$` is to enable https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/ANSI_002dC-Quoting.html and you must use it if you want it to work as advertised.

Answer (score 21):

Don't save trivial one and two character commands on the history list:

```
HISTIGNORE='?:??'
```

If the `extglob` option is enabled, you can also use extended patterns, e.g.

```
HISTIGNORE='a*( )'
```

Comment: Am not sure about your `??`, but sometimes I do `od /path/of/important/file` and I need to remember this.

Comment: `*` works as an arbitrary length placeholder as well. So for example for my custom history search shortcut, I use `h *`, so that these searches don't show up in the history itself again.

Comment: @daparic `od` matches `??` but `od /path/of/important/file` does not.